# Root cause for Invalid arguments in call (ORA-17068)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

We are getting **Invalid arguments in call** when we try to establish the connection with Oracle DB **occasionally** ( One hour in a day).

I did some research about this in Internet, still i am not getting clear understanding about the root cause of this exception.

**Please note:**

This is happens in PROD environment for sometime, after which its getting resolved without any code fix, the major concern here for us is that we don't have a clear understanding on its root cause.

**Question 1**

**Invalid arguments in call :**  is this message talking about the connection parameters that is sent to establish connection?

**Question 2**
If question 1 is true, why is it happening occasionally? Its highly unlikely that our application sends different parameter for establishing connection as its a binary (Connection parameters are constant).

**NOTE:** Documentation for ORA-17068 this error code is not available in oracle site

**EDIT:**

*Complete Exception trace:*

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.cpdsadapter.DriverAdapterCPDS.getPooledConnection(DriverAdapterCPDS.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.cpdsadapter.DriverAdapterCPDS.getPooledConnection(DriverAdapterCPDS.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.datasources.InstanceKeyDataSource.testCPDS(InstanceKeyDataSource.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.datasources.PerUserPoolDataSource.registerPool(PerUserPoolDataSource.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.datasources.PerUserPoolDataSource.getPooledConnectionAndInfo(PerUserPoolDataSource.java:382)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.datasources.InstanceKeyDataSource.getConnection(InstanceKeyDataSource.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.datasources.InstanceKeyDataSource.getConnection(InstanceKeyDataSource.java:676)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest, seeing as this is such an odd/rare error, you should open a support ticket with Oracle. That's why you pay the $$$$ for your support contract.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your suggestion. But do you have idea when we will get Invalid arugments in the call exception, i mean the reason ?

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from a connection being established? Might be helpful to show the stack trace and the code that identifies?

Comment: Did you check if any file is generated in trace directory and/or anything logged into alert.log ?

Comment: @igr : we are not the owner of oracle database server. so we couldn't check those logs.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes this occurs while establishing connection with Oracle server. please see the exception trace above

Comment: Please add things like that to the question, not as comments. Which JDBC driver version are you using? The only reference I can see to ORA-17068 on MOS is a JDBC error, but that is LOB related; still, making sure you're on the [latest 11gR2 driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) might make it go away. Phil's right though, you should really ask Oracle, or at least ask the DBAs to check the logs if you can't.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks for your suggestion, will work on them

Comment: I also faced this issue. I am able to get the connection and retrieve the query results as well. I got this exception when I try to subString a CLOB column data. I gave the index as 0 as the starting index. It gave 17068 exception. The index should start from 1.